# Syslog-ng custom parser

Tags: syslog-ng

Is it possible to implement custom parsers in syslog-ng ? For example, I want to implement a custom parser which will parse messages in ASN format and write the contents of the message to a file in ASCII format. Would it be possible ?

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can write custom parsers in Python. The Python parser is available in the latest version of the Premium Edition (commercial product), and it will be available in the upcoming 3.10 version of the Open Source Edition.
You can read about it in the documentation of the Premium Edition at https://www.balabit.com/documents/syslog-ng-pe-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-pe-guide-admin/html/python-parser.html

If you compile the current master branch of the Open Source Edition, it should include the Python parser. I think there is also a nightly rpm package somewhere that includes it - I'll check it and get back to you tomorrow.

Comment: You can find RPM packages from the current master branch here: https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/czanik/syslog-ng-githead/

Installation howto: https://www.balabit.com/blog/rpm-packages-from-syslog-ng-git-head/

Comment: Provided link is obsolete.

Comment: Hi, the new link is https://www.syslog-ng.com/community/b/blog/posts/rpm-packages-from-syslog-ng-git-head 
. You might also find this post useful: https://www.syslog-ng.com/community/b/blog/posts/build-syslog-ng-rpm-patched-git-sources-rhel-centos-7